# Separating Parameters in Repeated Function Calls

Tags: r, loops, vector, parameters, replicate

With a vector of values, I want each value to be called on a function

```
values = 1:10
rnorm(100, mean=values, sd=1)
```

mean = values repeats the sequence (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). How can I get a matrix, each with 100 observations and using a single element from my vector?
ie:

```
rnorm(100, mean=1, sd=1)
rnorm(100, mean=2, sd=1)
rnorm(100, mean=3, sd=1)
rnorm(100, mean=4, sd=1)
# ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but I took it that you wanted a single matrix with 10 rows and 100 columns. That being the case you can do:

```r
matrix(rnorm(1000, rep(1:10, each = 100)), nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

Or modify akrun's answer by using `sapply` instead of `lapply`

Answer (score 4):

An option is `lapply` from `base R`

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) rnorm(100, mean = i, sd = 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Or `Map` from base `R`:

```
Map(function(i) rnorm(100, mean = i, sd = 1), 1:10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *map* I can apply a function for each value from the vector ***values***

```
library(purrr)

values = 1:10
map_dfc(
  .x = values,
  .f = ~rnorm(100,mean = .x,sd = 1)
  )
```

In this case I will have a data.frame 100x10